# Send email to referrals in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode, ultimate-member

i have been having serious difficulties trying to send email from WordPress using custom code.
Details:
I am using Ultimate Member plugin and Wp Referral Code Plugin on my website to effect a real estate affiliate program.
I want it that when a use use A signs up with user B's referral link, user B should get an email of the following details about user A: Full Name, Email and mobile number.

i have tried all i can even using several the Wp Referral Code plugin support [articles](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-admin-can-inspect-new-users-are-receiving-membership-links-from-whom/)

`i am abit new to php for wordpress so i really need help.

Finally, i have a registration form from Ultimate Member Plugin that i use for users signups. the registration link looks like [this](https://portal.sdrealtorsnetwork.com/register?ref=wkit), 'wkit' here represents a referral code form a user. I want to be able to use the code to parse the full name of the user whose referral link is being used into a simple text field on the registration form (field will be locked)

```
`here is what i have tried for the email:

 function send_referral_email_with_details($new_user_id, $referrer_user_id) {
// Get the referrer's details
$referrer_data = get_userdata($referrer_user_id);
$referrer_name = $referrer_data->full_name;
$referrer_email = $referrer_data->user_email;

// Get the new user's details
$new_user_data = get_userdata($new_user_id);
$new_user_name = $new_user_data->full_name;
$new_user_email = $new_user_data->user_email;
$new_user_mobile = $new_user_data->mobile_number;

// Construct the email
$subject = 'New Referral Registration Notice on SD Realtors Network!';
$body = '<html>
            <head>
                <!-- Your styles here -->
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>New Referral Registration Notice on SD Realtors Network!</h1>
         <p>Hello, ' . $referrer_name . '!<br>Someone just Registered using your Referral    link.</p>
                    <h3>Details of New User</h3>
                    <p>Full Name: ' . $new_user_name . '</p>
                    <p>Email: ' . $new_user_email . '</p>
                    <p>Mobile Number: ' . $new_user_mobile . '</p>
              <p>If you have any problems, please contact us at <a        

            sdrealtorsnetwork1@gmail.com</a></p>




                </div>
            </body>
        </html>';
   $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

   // Send the email
  wp_mail($referrer_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

}

```
here is what i have tried for the Registration form:
 add_filter( 'um_pre_register_form', function($form) {
// Check for referral code in URL parameter
if (isset($_GET['ref'])) {
$ref_code = sanitize_text_field($_GET['ref']);
// Use plugin function to get upline user ID based on referral code
$upline_user_id = wp_referral_code_get_user_id_by_code($ref_code);

 // If upline user found, retrieve their full name
 if ($upline_user_id) {
  $upline_user = get_user_by('id', $upline_user_id);
  $upline_full_name = $upline_user->display_name;

    // Add new field to registration form
    $form->add_field('upline_name', array(
    ' type' => 'label',
     'label' => __('Referred by:', 'your-textdomain'),
     'value' => $upline_full_name,
     'readonly' => true,
   ));
  }
}
 return $form;
 });
 function shalihor_get_referrer_info($atts) {
```

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$referrer_id = get_user_meta($user_id, 'wrc_referrer_id', true);

```
if ($referrer_id) {
 $referrer_user = get_user_by('id', $referrer_id);
 $data = array(
  'full_name' => $referrer_user->display_name,
  // Retrieve other desired referrer data here
);
return shortcode_atts($atts, $data);
} else {
return '';
  }
  }
  add_shortcode('shalihor_referrer_info', 'shalihor_get_referrer_info');``






 both did not work,sad. i spent several nights doing this.
```

Comment: You haven't explained exactly what is happening here.